# Should I CreateSprite (2D) images based on the largest target screen resolution (android)?

Tags: android, image, opengl-es

I am about to make my second game on android. The first one, jackheart- slot/jackpot like game (image based game (non OPEN GL))  like a programming training so in the making i didn't really concern about the size or resolution of all the images i used in the game. the result was, some of my image didn't look good in tablet.

now i am making 2D OpenGL game, it will be a super mario bros alike game. my largest target screen resolution is 2560 x 1600 pixels  (samsung tablet 10.5), and my smallest target is 320x480 (galaxy young).

what i am about to do is creating images based on that 2560 x 1600 screen resolution:

1. create background picture =  2560 x 1600 pixels  (as it covers all
   the screen)
2. sprite/character = 120x120  (I used 32x32 for my first game)

could you really give me some input and advise regarding this..is it okay or not ?,  i actually no clue and enough undestanding about this image thing.

i read some article out there that said that i can provide images for different target by storing it in folder drawable m,l,x dpi..  , i don't really know about that, is it automatically read by android or what ? because i am storing all my images in Assets folder and load it all in the load Asset class before launching the main menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nah, I do checking in my load, read user screen res and load the proper image.
that's worked.